# The url structure of Trello

Tags: single-page-application, trello

The urls in trello are like this:
https://trello.com/board/board_name/501397ee70eb3347473f7452

Since trello is a single page application how is it possible to have such url i.e with no '#'.
Each of these urls should have been generating a GET request to server since they are different and hence causing a full page load. Does any one have an explanation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that Trello uses HTML5 pushState and Backbone.js.

More on pushState here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

More on Backbone.js here:
http://backbonejs.org/